# c# Ionic.zip - how to extract a password protected zip

Tags: c#

How can I extract a password protected zip using ionic?Non password protected zips get extracted fine,but the password protected ones return exception.

```
string selected_zip = FileListBox.GetItemText(FileListBox.SelectedItem);
String TargetDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Aristomenis\\Desktop\\" + selected_zip;
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zippy = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(TargetDirectory))
{
    zippy.ExtractAll("c:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\",
    Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Oh, it seems that `zippy.Password = "the_correct_password"` did the trick.

```
zippy.Password = "the_correct_password"
zippy.ExtractAll("c:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\",
            Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
```

Comment: It's also in the documentation too: https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples